# Spring - Send List of Objects to View and back to Post only one Object in controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I want to show users and edit or remove them like in the picture. The problem is, how can I post only one Object or identify an Object in the list to edit or delete?

I guess edit and delete should submit 2 params: one to identify what kind of operation is (edit, delete) and another to say what object in the list to modidy (maybe the index?).

[image]

I have the following methods in controller:

User form is a wrapper class, is a list of users following [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/) tutorial

```
/** Default GET form handler for MaganeUsers, in submission will call listusers */
@RequestMapping(value="admin/manageusers",  method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String listusers(Model model) {
    List<User> users = userService.listUsersDetails();
    UserForm userform = new UserForm();
    userform.setUserForm(users);

    model.addAttribute("userForm", userform);       
    return "admin/manageusers";
}
```

This is my jsp printing the table:

```
<c:if test="${not empty userForm}">
<sf:form method="post" action="manageusers" modelAttribute="userForm">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>User Roles</th>
    <th>Enabled</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${userForm.userForm}" var="users" varStatus="i">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">${i.count}</td>
        <td><sf:input path="userForm[${i.index}].username" value="${users.username}"/></td>
        <td><sf:input path="userForm[${i.index}].userRole" value="${users.userRole}"/></td>
        <td><sf:input path="userForm[${i.index}].enabled" value="${users.enabled}"/></td>
        <td><button name="submit" value="i">Edit</button><button name="submit" value="i">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table> 
</sf:form>
</c:if>
```

And my method to manage the submission post:

```
/** Default GET form handler for MaganeUsers, in submission will call listusers */
@RequestMapping(value="admin/manageusers",  method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteuser(Model model, @ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm) {
    ....
    // code here?
    userService.deleteUser(username);
    return "admin/manageusers";
}
```

I think I should add something in the JSP to send params and manage them in the post holder, but dont know how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should handle edit and delete in separate controller methods.
2. Change your submit buttons to  input type="button" and handle on click js event where you can build the logic to decide which controller method has to be called(may be can build the url dynamically) and submit it from js.
3. After the operation of edit/delete you may need to call the get which in turn queries the db and user can see the latest results on your jsp.